# SAM S70 Microcontroller - Need to use 2 functions on one pin

Tags: microcontroller, arm, peripheral, cortex-m7

I need to connect a SAM S70 (ARM® Cortex®-M7 based microcontroller) to both a camera and an eMCC FLASH.  The problem is that the PA27 pin has both MCDA3 and ISI_D7 as PIO Peripheral functions.  How do I handle this?  Do I have to switch the function of the pin each time, meaning I can only use one device at a time?  Is there something else I can do?

Comment: How do you plan on making the camera ignore the commands to the eMMC and vice-versa? I haven't looked at the datasheet for that processor, but can you re-assign those functions to another pin?

Comment: It seems those signals aren't available on other pins. However, I think eMMC interface might be configured with smaller bus widths, so you could use that feature to use PA27 exclusively for the camera, at the expense of eMMC bandwidth. Maybe.

Comment: @RonBeyer  As far as I can tell, I cannot assign either function to another pin.  However, that is the only pin the two interfaces have in common.  I haven't gotten far enough to know if it's a problem to use it for both interfaces, just switching the function of the pin when I want to use it.  I was hoping someone else had a similar problem and found a wise solution.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign the functions to another pin.  Other packages in the same processor family have the same issue.  I found some ST processors that might have worked, but none are available (Jan 2022).  Two possiblilties for using the S70 processor with the camera and eMMC interface are actually switching the functions of the pin (which means that both cannot be used at the same time) or using the one data wire configuration in the MMC interface.